# Looking for a better way to solve this system of equations.....

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

The Question :

Solve for real $x, y$ :
$$xy^2 = 15x^2 + 17xy + 15y^2$$ 
$$x^2y= 20x^2 + 3y^2$$

My initial attempts involved adding and subtracting the two equations, eliminating one variable, completing some squares and so on. But there was no significant progress as I soon reached a dead end.

The way I was actually able to solve this problem was somewhat unusual : I divided the equations to get $\frac {y}{x} = \frac{15x^2 +17xy + 15y^2}{20x^2 + 3y^2}$.  Seemed a very hopeless start, but soon I realised that I could divide the numerator and denominator by $x^2$ on Right Hand Side of the equation, which allowed me to substitute $\frac {y}x= m$. Clearing the denominator, I obtained a cubic equation in $m$ which factored as $(m^2+1)(m-5)=0$. As $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, I rejected the $m^2 +1 = 0$ possibility and got $m=5$ and hence $y = 5x$. After using this relation, I finally got the ordered pair $(x,y) \equiv (19,95)$ as the solution.

I feel that my method is very "robotic" and unnecessarily complicated. Is there any shorter, better, or more elegant way of solving this problem ? I am unable to find any other approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Robotic or not, congratulations on solving it!  I'm trying to see if there's some obvious simplifying features of the original equations, but nothing's coming to me yet ...

Comment: I think your method is clever, not robotic. The equations are _nearly_ homogeneous so that substitution stands a good chance of being useful.

Comment: You can also solve the4 second equation for $x$ $$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3y^2}{y-20}}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How does that help?

Comment: How does that not help?

Comment: You will get an equation only in $y$!!!!!!

Comment: I don't know if it is useful but there is an even more "robotic" way to solve it: taking the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) with respect to $y$ you obtain:
$$x^3(823650 - 4335 x + 285 x^2 - 15 x^3)$$
with only real roots $19$ and $0$ then you can take $x=0$ and $x=19$ and see the corresponding equations in $y$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your method is fine. Over the complex numbers we obtain the solutions
$$
(x,y)=(0,0),(19,95),(-17i,17),(17i,17),
$$
by taking the resultant with respect to $y$, which is
$$
15x^4(x^2+17^2)(x-19)=0.
$$